# Construct user specific HTML after processing with JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am developing an HTML page that should be user specific. I need to pass the user name as a query string parameter and it should check the groups the user is part of, and according to user groups, it should display the HTML page. (Different for different users).

The method I am taking along is that I have made a JSP page that will extract the query string parameter using a servlet. I will then call an API for my application using JAR file and fetch the user groups in an ArrayList. After getting the user groups I need to display the HTML page. The HTML page is static just the thumbnails/buttons are different according to the groups fetched.

I have seen many answers to similar questions about constructing HTML dynamically but I am not able to figure out which approach to use as I am a beginner. Should I generate it with JavaScript,jquery,templates or any other method?

Also, I need to understand the workflow that how this whole process will work i.e. what activities would be performed on server side and client side and how?

I would really appreciate any help.

Best Regards,

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to display the dynamic content using JavaScript InnerHTML method.

I have done the server side part in JSP and client side in JavaScript. What I have done is that, at server side in JSP, I fetch the username from header of request. Then I use it in my Application-specific API to get information about the user's groups. I pass this user's group list to the JavaScript function where I compare the user's groups with an already stored/hard coded group list in a var in JavaScript function. Depending on each group, if it is found in the groups list, I add innerHTML to the respective div using its id. The HTML to add via innerHTML method is also hard coded in a var in the JavaScript function.

Being a beginner that's how I have populated dynamic content on the page. There must be better ways to do that and would be interested to know that if somebody would like to help.

Best Regards